# Regular expression matching digits and space

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to match a string containing 1 to 3 digits,

example:

```
1
 2
123
  3
```

This is what i tried,

```
[\s]?[0-9]{1,3}[\s]?
```

This is matching,

```
123 ->a space after 123
```

Comment: What's the question? And what language/platform is this?

Comment: Java.  I should be able to match 1 to 3 digits, when i tried, it is matching 123space

Comment: So, the string should contain 1-3 digits (0-9) and _nothing_ else?

Comment: `\s` matches whitespace, so it's only doing what you told it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is unclear, but it seems you're looking for a string that

- is exactly 3 characters long
- contains only digits or whitespace
- contains at least one digit

In that case, the regex is `^(?=.*\d)[\d\s]{3}$`. As a Java string: `"^(?=.*\\d)[\\d\\s]{3}$"`.

**Explanation:**

```
^         # Start of string
(?=.*\d)  # Assert that there is at least one digit in the string
[\d\s]{3} # Match 3 digits or whitespace characters
$         # End of string
```

Comment: Yeah, it works.  Thanks.  But, i am not sure, my question is unclear, i have given the exact example which string should match.  Not clear why its getting down voted.

Comment: It's not my downvote, but  you're asking for "a string containing 1 to 3 digits", which is a condition fulfilled by strings like `"a1b2c3"` or `"    3   21     "` etc. - The fact that you got five different answers, all of which have interpreted your question differently, should make it clear that the problem was not clearly defined.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you

`^\\d{1,3}$`.

Explanation

```
"^" +     // Assert position at the beginning of the string
"\\d" +    // Match a single digit 0..9
"{1,3}" +   // Between one and 3 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
"$"       // Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any)
```

Comment: It does not match if there is space

Comment: @FirmView Exact requirement is not clear from the question. Do you want to match a space or do you don't?

Answer (score 0):

Could you use word boundary meta character in your regex engine? try with this: `\b\d{1,3}\b`

Answer (score 0):

The pattern to match up to 3 digits, with any amount of leading whitespace and no trailing whitespace, would be: `^\s*\d{1,3}$`.

This would match:

```
1
 2
123
  3
```

But would not match "123 ", with a space at the end.